# CoffeeScript do, pass argument

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

The following CoffeeScript code:

```
do (a) ->
    console.log a
```

generates this:

```
(function(a) {
  return console.log(a);
})(a);
```

How do I pass a value to a like this?

```
(function(a) {
  return console.log(a);
})("hello");
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
do (a = 'hello') ->
  console.log a
```

Will [generate](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3ado%20%28a%3D%27hello%27%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20console.log%20a) exactly what you want.

Though, i have to admit that i can't see the point of doing that. If you really want `a` to take the literal value `'hello'` inside that scope, then why make another scope? With `a` being a normal variable declared as `a = 'hello'` will be enough. Now, if you want to replace `a` with the value of another variable (that might change in a loop or something) and do `do (a = b) ->` then i think it makes more sense, but you could simple do `do (a) ->` and just use `a` instead of `b` inside the `do` scope.

Comment: `do($ = jQuery) ->` is a commom use case

Comment: it's good for use inside loop that creates multiple closures, so that each loop iteration (each closure) has it's own variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html), this is useful to use the $ global when using multiple Javascript libraries that may conflict with each other:

```
mySingleton = do ($ = jQuery) -> 
   colorIt -> $('.colorme').css('backgroundColor', 'red')

mySingleton.colorIt()
```

Answer (score 2):

`do` is a special keyword in CoffeeScript. It creates a closure. I think you want something like this:

```
log = (msg) ->
  console.log msg
```

Compiles to:

```
var log;

log = function(msg) {
  return console.log(msg);
};
```

Use it like any other function: `log("hello")`

Answer (score 2):

you could do this

```
do (a = "foo")->
    console.log a
```

But really why would you do this?
WHat is the more complete use case you are trying to implement

Comment: Purely to understand CoffeeScript better. Thanks for the answer!